# Troubles with serializer for proxy models DRF/DJANGO

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am new in DRF, so it might be simple question....
I have a question regarding serializes in DRF:

I have a following Models:

```py
class Heading(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, db_index=True, unique=True, verbose_name='heading '
                                                                                    'title')
    order = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0, db_index=True, verbose_name='Order')
    foreignkey = models.ForeignKey("UpperHeading", on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True,
                                   blank=True, verbose_name="Upper heading", )
    one_to_one_to_boat = models.OneToOneField(BoatModel, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,blank=True, verbose_name="correspondent boat for the category", )
    change_date = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, editable=False, auto_now=True)


#    primary model

class UpperHeadingManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return models.Manager.get_queryset(self).filter(foreignkey__isnull=True)


class UpperHeading(Heading):
    objects = UpperHeadingManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        ordering = ("order", "name")
        verbose_name = "Upper heading"
        verbose_name_plural = "Upper headings"

#  secondary model

class SubHeadingManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return models.Manager.get_queryset(self).filter(foreignkey__isnull=False)


class SubHeading(Heading):
    objects = SubHeadingManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s - %s" % (self.foreignkey.name, self.name)

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        ordering = ("foreignkey__name", "name")
        verbose_name = "Sub heading"
        verbose_name_plural = "Sub headings"
```

I want to make serializer for the model Upperheading in a  such way that it would include secondary model’s “SubHeading” related data

Here is what I written:

```py
class UpperHeadingSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=20, required=True, allow_blank=False)
    order = serializers.IntegerField()
    subheading_set = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return UpperHeading.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.name = validated_data.get("name", "instance.name")
        instance.order = validated_data.get("order", "instance.order")
        instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = UpperHeading
        fields = ("id", "name", "order", "subheading_set")
```

Logically if UpperHeading is a main model and SubHeading is a secondary one, reverse related manager should be as default “subheading_set”.  In my serializers.py I specified this relation in the field

```py
subheading_set = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
```

but when I am trying to use this serializer I getting an exception:

```py
AttributeError at /api/upperheadings/
'UpperHeading' object has no attribute 'subheading_set'
```

Question is what should I use as a backward related manager in DRF then?  These 2 models are proxy models and they dont have related manager or have it in a non-standard way.

```py
 a = UpperHeading.objects.first()
>>> a.subheading_set
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'UpperHeading' object has no attribute 'subheading_set'
```

It seems like in a proxy models reverse related manager isnt supported

Anyway, is it any chance to serialize relationship between 2 models?

Thank you!